# Translate numbers (IP address) inside a variable (bash)

Tags: bash, sed, grep, ip, translate

My problem is that I'm having an IP address like `10.3.1.33`
This IP address is inside a variable `ip=10.3.1.33`

Now I want to translate the `33` inside that IP address with a "*".
The "33" can change, so that this number has to be automatically put somewhere in a variable or so.....
I have no clue how to do that. Thanks for any advice :)

Comment: the word translate implies that there are "rules" to your conversion. If you had `34` instead, that you would want to convert to `%`. I don't this is really the case, so to "replace" one value with another in a variable, you can do `ip=10.3.1.33 ; ip=${ip/33/\*/} ; echo :"ip=$ip"` Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your very specific case you could use:

```
$ ip="10.3.1.33"
$ printf "%s\n" "${ip/33/*}"
10.3.1.*
```

And to replace (remove) everything after the last period:

```
$ ip="10.3.1.33"
$ printf "%s\n" "${ip%.*}.*"
10.3.1.33
```

The later is POSIX compatible while the first is available in bash (among other shells)

Comment: how to make the 33 become variable? This IP Adress can be anything, so I dont want to put the last octett of the ip inside your code by myself every time

Comment: @tso Doesn't the second snippet do exactly that? Removing the last part of the ip, and then adding `.*`

Answer (score 1):

I can think about this:

```
 ip=1.2.3.4
 ip1=${ip%.*}.*
```